# Generating same random unique number every time for a given number

Tags: scala, random, mapping, random-seed

We are having a set of groups and each group will have billions of records. Each group will uniquely identified by an id and each record in a group will be uniquely identified by an id. By combining these two ids(concat(groupid, recordid)) we can identify a record across the groups.

Now we are trying to change these id (concatenated) values, in our reports we don't want to share the direct ids with the customers that we are maintaining, rather we want to convert the ids to some other uniqueid and share that with the customers, so that it will be difficult for them to identify the group.

We have tried generating hash (hmac256 hashing) values for this, but that didn't work for our customer as it has increased their storage drastically. If the current id is of 20 digit length, and generating 45 characters hash is not working. So looking for a better option in generating 20 digit/string or at least 25 digit/string unique value which will not be having collisions.

Looking for some inputs on this.

We have tried generating hash (hmac256 hashing) values for this, but that didn't work for our customer as it has increased their storage drastically. If the current id is of 20 digit length, and generating 45 characters hash is not working.

Example:
groupId=910612349078
recordId=6234091234

for the above two values, the unique id that system generates as of today will be looking like as below:
uniqueId=9106123490786234091234 (concat(groupId, recordId))

The expected behavior for unique id will be some random/hash value:
newUniqueId = some hash or some random number

Comment: Could you clarify size of group ID and record ID? Are they fit within 64bit space?

Comment: Does `concat(129,87)` produce a different result than `concat(12,987)`?

Comment: Thats a very good point, but when we create a group id we are making sure that the group id will not be having sub string collisions. The group id generation itself is a job which takes care of these cases. So we will never be having this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would try is to use decent fast secure hash function - [ChaCha20](http://loup-vaillant.fr/tutorials/chacha20-design).

ChaCha20 produces pseudorandom blocks of 64 bytes each, which are XORed with the data to encrypted or decrypt. It requires 256-bit key and 64-bit nonce. Assuming all your Ids fits into 64bit (20 digits, after all, are pretty close to 2<sup>64</sup>-1 which is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615), set your key, use group Id as nonce, and encrypt you record Id XORing ChaCha20 output with it.

You didn't mention platform, so no code, but there are tons of good implementations in C/C++/Go/Rust/...

UPDATE

You could try to use ChaCha20 as block cipher in counter mode. Then your input would be key, 64bit group id as nonce, and 64bit record id as counter. Output would be 64bit block which you send to customers.

Ok, I played with Monocypher implementation (link at the bottom of the ChaCha20 page), and for use it as block cipher as proposed above. So far it looks good to me - different groupId/recordId produced distinctively different scrambled values. Code is in C++, compiles with LLVM 8 and MSVC++19.2. I put whole project on Github [here](https://github.com/Kri-Ol/ChaCha20).

```
uint64_t scramble(const uint64_t groupId,
                  const uint64_t recordId,
                  const char*    text_key = nullptr)
{
    uint8_t key[32] = {0x1c, 0x92, 0x40, 0xa5, 0xeb, 0x55, 0xd3, 0x8a,
                       0xf3, 0x33, 0x88, 0x86, 0x04, 0xf6, 0xb5, 0xf0,
                       0x47, 0x39, 0x17, 0xc1, 0x40, 0x2b, 0x80, 0x09,
                       0x9d, 0xca, 0x5c, 0xbc, 0x20, 0x70, 0x75, 0xc0}; // same key as in example 3 below
    if (text_key != nullptr) {
        hex2byte(text_key, key);
    }

    const uint8_t* nonce = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&groupId); // nonce would be our group id
    crypto_chacha_ctx ctx;
    crypto_chacha20_init(&ctx, key, nonce); // initialize ChaCha20

    crypto_chacha20_set_ctr(&ctx, recordId); // block counter is our record Id

    uint64_t input = 0x0000000000000000; // Just get the block out. Chacha will make random block and XOR it with input text.
                                         // XOR with zeroes preserve Chacha block.
                                         // Or 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF to get it iverted
    uint64_t output;
    crypto_chacha20_encrypt(&ctx,
                            reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&output),
                            reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&input),
                            sizeof(input));

    return output;
}


int main()
{
    // Test values from http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-nir-cfrg-chacha20-poly1305-04#appendix-A.2
    srand(123); //Test results will be consistent
    test_ietf_chacha20("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0000000000000000", "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "76b8e0ada0f13d90405d6ae55386bd28bdd219b8a08ded1aa836efcc8b770dc7da41597c5157488d7724e03fb8d84a376a43b8f41518a11cc387b669b2ee6586", 0, 1);
    test_ietf_chacha20("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", "0000000000000002", "416e79207375626d697373696f6e20746f20746865204945544620696e74656e6465642062792074686520436f6e7472696275746f7220666f72207075626c69636174696f6e20617320616c6c206f722070617274206f6620616e204945544620496e7465726e65742d4472616674206f722052464320616e6420616e792073746174656d656e74206d6164652077697468696e2074686520636f6e74657874206f6620616e204945544620616374697669747920697320636f6e7369646572656420616e20224945544620436f6e747269627574696f6e222e20537563682073746174656d656e747320696e636c756465206f72616c2073746174656d656e747320696e20494554462073657373696f6e732c2061732077656c6c206173207772697474656e20616e6420656c656374726f6e696320636f6d6d756e69636174696f6e73206d61646520617420616e792074696d65206f7220706c6163652c207768696368206172652061646472657373656420746f", "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", 1, 2);
    test_ietf_chacha20("1c9240a5eb55d38af333888604f6b5f0473917c1402b80099dca5cbc207075c0", "0000000000000002", "2754776173206272696c6c69672c20616e642074686520736c6974687920746f7665730a446964206779726520616e642067696d626c6520696e2074686520776162653a0a416c6c206d696d737920776572652074686520626f726f676f7665732c0a416e6420746865206d6f6d65207261746873206f757467726162652e", "62e6347f95ed87a45ffae7426f27a1df5fb69110044c0d73118effa95b01e5cf166d3df2d721caf9b21e5fb14c616871fd84c54f9d65b283196c7fe4f60553ebf39c6402c42234e32a356b3e764312a61a5532055716ead6962568f87d3f3f7704c6a8d1bcd1bf4d50d6154b6da731b187b58dfd728afa36757a797ac188d1", 42, 3);
    std::cout << '\n';

    uint64_t scrambled{0ULL};

    scrambled = scramble(10, 12345);
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << scrambled << '\n';
    scrambled = scramble(100, 12345);
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << scrambled << '\n';
    scrambled = scramble(11, 12345); // group id differ by 1
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << scrambled << '\n';
    scrambled = scramble(10, 12346); // record id differ by 1
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << scrambled << '\n';
    scrambled = scramble(0, 0);
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << scrambled << '\n';
    scrambled = scramble(0, 1);
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << scrambled << '\n';
    scrambled = scramble(1, 0);
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << scrambled << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output from last 7 lines is

```
0x6321d1e43d4ab340
0x7dd7e1cfab075076
0x1e8483e0081fa6ee
0xb6084d3151900667
0x7794b6c405fbf46
0x115ddf32dffd75df
0x87a199dff4e4326a
```

UPDATE II

Sorry, I made a typo which probably misled you (stated size of the block as 64bits when it is 64bytes, corrected now).

Yes, block size is 64bytes (actually 16 uint32_t of 32bits). And ChaCha20 is  able to produce 2<sup>64</sup> such blocks. So you could make your input size say 12 bytes and output would be first 12 bytes of the block. Please check update code in the repo. I've inverted printing the 12bytes block to show it is the same as before (endianness). You could put any scrambled size up to 64.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information, let me get back by doing a poc on this. We are using scala-spark. As you said platform shouldn't be a matter as long as context is matching.

Comment: @Krish you're welcome. PLease check update for another potential implementation

Comment: I did a POC on this to understand this cipher, looks like I there is an issue in this, here I am sharing an example with details. Let me know if this makes sense to you and then we will see how to overcome out of this issue. Example: Key: mykey, groupid (nonce): 10, recordId:12345, for my given key and nonce it has produced some key stream value,  which is good. Now I changed my group id to 100, this also produced key stream value and is same the one produced by group id 10. Assume that both the groups has record id 12345, then both these produces same encrypted text, then this will issue.

Comment: @Krish Interesting... I'll look at it on weekend

Comment: Thanks for the update, will check and come back on this.

Comment: Thanks Severin, after spending some more time in understanding this, it worked for me. Now I am able to generate the unique value which is distinct. Do  you know any other mechanism which can extend this pseudorandom (any other unique hashing mechanism) blocks to more than 64 bits. Our combined unique id (for very few groups where group id itself is 13 digits and record id is 8 digits) is exceeding the 2^64-1 value. We may not be exceeding this limit always but for very few records we have this overflow.

Comment: @Krish Sure, you could extend scrambled result up to 64bytes. Please check update

Comment: @Krish Sorry for typo, happens sometimes. We had something similar (though not on top of ChaCha, different cipher, you actually made me look at ChaCha20 and I like what I see so far, will continue to hack it). What we do we're keeping key as a company secret. Then some cipher produce block and at the end we encrypt per-client string, so final input is not 0x000000000000, but string "clientABC" or "clientXYZ", thus removing inter-clients correlations. Anyway, good luck!